# Object color apply does not work?

Tags: three.js

I have loaded object in three js. When i apply the color it does not work.

I have below code used i got error in,

> child.material.color is undefined

I have used below code

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 0.8, 1 );
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( file, function ( object ) { 
  object.traverse( function ( child ) {
    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
       child.material.ambient.setHex(0xFF0000);
         child.material.color.setHex(0x00FF00);
    }
   } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think child.material.color.setHex() is enough to apply/set the color of an object.
So try to remove the following line from your code.
`child.material.ambient.setHex(0xFF0000);`

Here is the working fiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ev3tuLuc/109/